# is possible to resolve a dns with pure js?

Tags: javascript

I need to resolve a dns name to adress ip with only the browser and javascript, is possible?

I searched in google and S.O but i view a lot of confused responses. I can't call externals apis at the web to make this for me, only .js pure in client side.

Greetings.

Comment: afaik only firefox exposes dns to javascript (`browser.dns.resolve` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns/resolve)

Comment: Even then, this is only available to a Firefox extension, not a normal page.